# Scripts don't run together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't run the two scripts together, is't an error of syntax ? 
Separately it works perfectly... 
The first is about my progress bar and the second is about typed.js animation.

Here a link to the code : https://jsfiddle.net/DATAPIX/m5p200ms/2/

Thank you for your help.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#cursor1").show(),jQuery("#screentyped-1").typed({strings:["Hello, my name is XXXX"],stringsstops:[0],typeSpeed:60,callback:function(){jQuery("#typed-cursor").remove(),jQuery("#cursor2").show(),jQuery("#screentyped-2").typed({strings:["I'm XXXXX"],stringsstops:[14,0],typeSpeed:50,callback:function(){jQuery("#typed-cursor").remove(),jQuery("#cursor3").show(),jQuery("#screentyped-3").typed({strings:["Je suis XXXX","Je suis XXXXXXXXXXXX."],stringsstops:[28,0],typeSpeed:50,callback:function(){clearInterval(r),clearInterval(i)}})}})}});var s=jQuery(".animation-element"),o=jQuery(window);o.on("scroll resize",e),o.trigger("scroll");
 
    
var $progress = $(".progress-bar");
var $section = $('.progress-bar');
var $queue = $({});
$(function() {

var $section = $('.progress-bar');

function loadDaBars() {
           $(".progress-element").each(function() {
      var progressBar = $(".progress-bar");
      progressBar.each(function(indx){
          $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%");
      });
  });
}

$(document).bind('scroll', function(ev) {
    var scrollOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
    var containerOffset = $section.offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if (scrollOffset > containerOffset) {
        loadDaBars();
        // unbind event not to load scrolsl again
        $(document).unbind('scroll');
    }
});
});            
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You can look in the browser's Javascript console and see for yourself if it's a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery but is it ok to define two onReady functions? Won't the second overwrite the first? He's currently using both `jquery(document).ready(...)` and `$(function(){...})`.

Comment: Thank you juhana and Aaron, I'm not familiar with query too. Do you know How I can write or work this two scripts together ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing your on ready event in the first script. If you are expecting them both to run when the page is ready then that's why they are not working.

If you beautify your first script(http://jsbeautifier.org/) it looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#cursor1").show(), jQuery("#screentyped-1").typed({
    strings: ["Hello, my name is XXXX"],
    stringsstops: [0],
    typeSpeed: 60,
    callback: function() {
      jQuery("#typed-cursor").remove(), jQuery("#cursor2").show(), jQuery("#screentyped-2").typed({
        strings: ["I'm XXXXX"],
        stringsstops: [14, 0],
        typeSpeed: 50,
        callback: function() {
          jQuery("#typed-cursor").remove(), jQuery("#cursor3").show(), jQuery("#screentyped-3").typed({
            strings: ["Je suis XXXX", "Je suis XXXXXXXXXXXX."],
            stringsstops: [28, 0],
            typeSpeed: 50,
            callback: function() {
              clearInterval(r), clearInterval(i)
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  });
  var s = jQuery(".animation-element"),
      o = jQuery(window);
  o.on("scroll resize", e), o.trigger("scroll");
```

You need to move the closing bracket, parentheses and semicolon to the end of your `<script>` tag in order to incorporate all of your code into the ready() event.

Comment: Ok. So what I do please ?

Comment: I edited my answer I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But sorry I'm not a jquery expert and I don't understand all in your answer.

Comment: Move the "});" to the end of your script tag. I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: If you're still confused this Jquery tutorial might help you out: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

Comment: But if I move }); to the end of scripts, that's not work too...

Comment: Open your developer console with F12 and send what error you are getting with your original code please.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DATAPIX/m5p200ms/

Comment: The last function don't work with the first

Comment: What is the last function supposed to do so that I know what to look for?

Comment: You can see "// Function 02" note in code lines . This function don't work. But if I delete the "Function 01" the "function 02" work perfect - it's a progress bar animation

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to use a jQuery library in which you haven't included yet.

In the console log, i am getting:
`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).typed is not a function`

Googling, I found this: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

try adding it to your script right below your jQuery call and see if it works then.

Comment: Yes, know this link.Thank you. But I test a other exemple with more options

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the end of my code and that's work. 
Thank you.

```html
 $("#cursor1").show(), $("#screentyped-1").typed({
                strings: ["Hello, my name is XXXX"],
                stringsstops: [0],
                typeSpeed: 60,
                callback: function() {
                    
$("#typed-cursor").remove(), $("#cursor2").show(), $("#screentyped-2").typed({
                        strings: ["I'm XXXXX"],
                        stringsstops: [14, 0],
                        typeSpeed: 50,
                        callback: function() {

$("#typed-cursor").remove(), $("#cursor3").show(), $("#screentyped-3").typed({
                                strings: ["Je suis XXXX", "Je suis XXXXXXXXXXXX."],
                                stringsstops: [28, 0],
                                typeSpeed: 50,
                                callback: function() {
                                    clearInterval(r), clearInterval(i)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
            
            var $progress = $(".progress-bar");
var $section = $('.progress-bar');
var $queue = $({});
$(function() {

var $section = $('.progress-bar');

function loadDaBars() {
           $(".progress-element").each(function() {
      var progressBar = $(".progress-bar");
      progressBar.each(function(indx){
          $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%");
      });
  });
}

$(document).bind('scroll', function(ev) {
    var scrollOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
    var containerOffset = $section.offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if (scrollOffset > containerOffset) {
        loadDaBars();
        // unbind event not to load scrolsl again
        $(document).unbind('scroll');
    }
});
});
            
            
            
            var s = $(".animation-element"),
                o = $(window);
            o.on("scroll resize", e), o.trigger("scroll");
```